# Error in using group_by and summarise in running correlation and test of significance with SPSS dataset

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation, summarize

I borrow a dataset from SPSS prepared by [Julie Pallant's SPSS Survival Manual](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3-euw1-ap-pe-ws4-cws-documents.ri-prod/9781760875534/survey.zip) and run it on R.

I select three columns to run correlation and significance test: toptim, tnegaff, sex. I select the columns using select: `df <- survey %>% select(toptim, tnegaff, sex)`.

Then, problems emerge.

1. I'd like to know the correlation between toptim and tnegaff by sex. But I can't use `cor` and resort to `correlate`. Why is there error and any difference between the two methods?

`df %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(cor = correlate(toptim, tnegaff))` <- OK (male = 0.22 female = 0.394)

`df %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(cor = cor(toptim, tnegaff))`  <- failed, returns with NA

2. I failed to obtain the test of significance with cor.test (The answer should be p = 0.0488)

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `cor = cor.test(toptim, tnegaff)`.
✖ `cor` must be a vector, not a `htest` object.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: sex = 1.
```

Then I try to follow past examples and use `broom::tidy`, but no output for p-values....

```
> df %>% group_by(sex) %>% broom::tidy(cor.test(toptim, tnegaff))
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  column      n  mean    sd median trimmed   mad   min   max range   skew kurtosis     se
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 toptim    435 22.1  4.43      22   22.3      3     7    30    23 NA        NA    0.212 
2 tnegaff   435 19.4  7.07      18   18.6      4    10    39    29 NA        NA    0.339 
3 sex       439  1.58 0.494      2    1.58     0     1     2     1 -0.318     1.10 0.0236
```

How can I get the result? May I know the reason for such failure?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to use all values and coming across `NA`s I presume. If you set to use `"complete.obs"` then it should work. For the `cor.test` part wrap the output in a `list` function to use the tibble's capabilities to have a column of a vector of objects.

For the final tidying and getting p-values, use `map(cor.test, broom::tidy)` then `tidyr::unnest()` to get a full and tidy dataframe.

That's a few steps to go through but hope it helps!

```r
df <- haven::read_sav("survey.sav")

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(cor = cor(toptim, tnegaff, use = "complete.obs"),
            cor.test = list(cor.test(toptim, tnegaff))) %>%
  mutate(tidy_out = map(cor.test, broom::tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidy_out)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>   sex        cor cor.t…¹ estim…² stati…³  p.value param…⁴ conf.…⁵ conf.…⁶ method
#>   <dbl+l>  <dbl> <list>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 1 [MAL… -0.220 <htest>  -0.220   -3.04 2.73e- 3     182  -0.353 -0.0775 Pears…
#> 2 2 [FEM… -0.394 <htest>  -0.394   -6.75 1.06e-10     248  -0.494 -0.284  Pears…
#> # … with 1 more variable: alternative <chr>, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   ¹​cor.test, ²​estimate, ³​statistic, ⁴​parameter, ⁵​conf.low, ⁶​conf.high
```

### Edit - examining difference in correlation

Borrowing the function from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/are-two-pearson-correlation-coefficients-different) you can examine the difference in correlation coefficients between sexes like this:

```r
cor.diff.test(df$toptim[df$sex == 1], df$tnegaff[df$sex == 1], df$toptim[df$sex == 2], df$tnegaff[df$sex == 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @andy-baxter. Actually the significance test I'd like to find out is the whether gender difference exists, not the p-value for each gender. Is there any way to tackle it?  The answer should be p = 0.0488 and there is gender difference.

Comment: I'm not sure how past examples using `broom::tidy` have done it - do you have a link for that? Borrowing the function from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/are-two-pearson-correlation-coefficients-different) you can do it like this: `cor.diff.test(df$toptim[df$sex == 1], df$tnegaff[df$sex == 1], df$toptim[df$sex == 2], df$tnegaff[df$sex == 2])`

Comment: (running the above function I get 0.0486, which seems to be consistent)

Comment: Ya, seems that your answer is in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the textbook suggests going to this website, input manually the n and cor to find the result: http://vassarstats.net/rdiff.html

Comment: Yes had found that one when looking up the book. helpful that it comes to the same conclusion. Have added the link and final bit of code to the answer if you want to check and mark as resolved if it fits your questions :)